# Eclipse Plug-in First executes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

From where an eclipse plug in will start?

As for as i know, class which extends abstract class plugin will run first.That class will start the bundle and plug-in.xml file will load.Am i correct?

If i am correct, Please tell me in Plug-in.xml which extension point will execute first and how that is determined ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not as simple as you describe. Most importantly, plug-ins/bundles are initially loaded by the platform without actually executing any code from them. The platform reads and evaluates the bundle manifest `plugin.xml` in order to know what extension points it uses, but only when one of those is actually invoked (usually triggered by user action) does it execute any code from the plug-in (including instantiating the bundle activator class, which usually is an extension of `Plugin`).

There are exceptions to this (basically plug-in eager start-up, but that's heavily discouraged), but this is the general concept.

Read more details in the [Eclipse wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_plug-in_manifest_file_(plugin.xml)%3F), [help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_model_bundles.htm), and [API docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FPlugin.html).